# Condense factor variables for duplicated ID´s in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame with duplicated ID´s. An ID stands for a specific entity. The ID´s are duplicated because the dataset refers to a process that every entity can go through multiple times.

Here is a small example `dat`:

```
library(dplyr)
glimpse(dat)
Observations: 6
Variables: 3
$ ID      <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
$ Amount  <dbl> 10, 70, 80, 50, 10, 10
$ Product <fct> A, B, C, B, E, A
```

`ID` stands for the entity, `Amount` stands for the amount of money the entity has spend and `Product` stands for the good the entity bought.

The issue is that I have to "condense" this data. So, every ID / entity may occur only once. For the continuous variable, this is not an issue because I can simply calculate the mean per ID.

```
library(tidyr)

dat_con_ID <- dat %>% 
    select(ID) %>% 
    unique()

dat_con_Amount <- dat %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(Amount = mean(Amount))

dat_con <- inner_join(dat_con_ID, dat_con_Amount, by = "ID")

glimpse(dat_con)
Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ ID     <dbl> 1, 2
$ Amount <dbl> 53.33333, 23.33333
```

The problem is, that I can´t calculate the mean of `Product` because it´s a categorical variable. An option would be to make a dummy variable out of this factor and calculate the mean. But since the original data frame is really huge this is not a good solution. Any Idea how to handle this problem?

Comment: Can you just make a sorted comma delimited string of `Product` items; so for `ID` of `1` you would have a single element string of `"A,B,C"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are trying to do this:

I am using `data.table` library. I also modified your data by adding one extra row for `ID = 1`, so that you can see the difference in the output.

**Data:**

```
library('data.table')
dat <- data.table(ID =as.double(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,1)),
                  Amount = as.double(c( 10, 70, 80, 50, 10, 10, 20)),
                  Product = factor( c('A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'A')))
```

**Code:**

```
# average amount per id
dat[, .(avg_amt = mean(Amount)), by = .(ID) ]
#    ID  avg_amt
# 1:  1 45.00000
# 2:  2 23.33333

# average product per id
dat[, .SD[, .N, by = Product ][, .( avg_pdt = N/sum(N), Product)], by = .(ID) ]
#    ID   avg_pdt Product
# 1:  1 0.5000000       A
# 2:  1 0.2500000       B
# 3:  1 0.2500000       C
# 4:  2 0.3333333       B
# 5:  2 0.3333333       E
# 6:  2 0.3333333       A

# combining average amount and average product per id
dat[, .SD[, .N, by = Product ][, .( Product,
                                    avg_pdt = N/sum(N), 
                                    avg_amt = mean(Amount))],
    by = .(ID) ]
#    ID Product   avg_pdt  avg_amt
# 1:  1       A 0.5000000 45.00000
# 2:  1       B 0.2500000 45.00000
# 3:  1       C 0.2500000 45.00000
# 4:  2       B 0.3333333 23.33333
# 5:  2       E 0.3333333 23.33333
# 6:  2       A 0.3333333 23.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

Another idea would be to `count` 'Product' as per 'ID', calculating the `mean` of 'Amount' and the relative frequencies for each product. `spread` the data by 'Product' to end up with the data in wide format. *So, every ID / entity may occur only once.*

```
dat %>% 
  add_count(Product, ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Amount = mean(Amount),
         n = n / n()) %>%
  unique() %>% 
  spread(Product, n, sep = "_") %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#     ID Amount Product_A Product_B Product_C Product_E
#  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1    1.   45.0     0.500     0.250     0.250    NA    
#2    2.   23.3     0.333     0.333    NA         0.333
```

---

My first attempt, not what OP was looking for but in case someone is interested:

As suggested by @steveb in the comments, you could summarise `Product` as a string.

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(Amount = mean(Amount),
           Product = toString( sort(unique(Product)))
           )
 # A tibble: 2 x 3
#     ID Amount Product
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  
#1    1.   45.0 A, B, C
#2    2.   23.3 A, B, E
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1), Amount = c(10, 70, 
80, 50, 10, 10, 20), Product = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "E"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Amount", "Product"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x2c14528>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: For reproducibility and remove duplicates, you may want to do `toString( sort(unique(Product)) )`.

Comment: I have also to aggregate the Information regarding the product. It must be like the relative frequency. If I would create dummy features an then calculate the mean I would get the information but it´s really time consuming.